# Rails route for mapping records by name rather than id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my Rails application, I would like to route /product/productname1, /product/productname2, etc. to ProductController::index(). I don't want separate methods in my ProductController for each product name route.

What would my route look like?

I have

```
map.connect 'products/:name', :controller => 'products', :action => 'index'
```

But when I go to

```
/products/something
```

I get

```
No action responded to show. Actions: index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to do with the ordering of your routes file? eg is this coming after map.resources :products?

Comment: Ah ha! You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Thanks! Moving map.resources :products below the map.connect line fixed the problem.